# Why can't I compile with iPhone OS 3.0 as a deployment target in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an iPhone app which was developed with 4.0 as the base SDK and a deployment target of 3.0. Everything was working fine.

Last week I upgraded to Xcode 4.2. Now when I open the existing project, I can't compile with a deployment target of 3.0. It compiles successfully and runs only when the deployment target is 4.0.

I get the following error when I set the target to 3.0:

> Unsupported compiler 'GCC 4.2' selected for architecture 'armv7'

The compiler which I use is LLVM 3.0. I am not using ARC.

Should I go back to the 3.x SDK? Is there a way that I can support 3.x using Xcode 4.2?

Comment: Maybe you should target armv6?

Answer (score 1):

Uhhh, don't?

That might sound flip but iOS 4 has achieved pretty good penetration. Looking at [Intstapaper's](http://www.marco.org/2011/08/13/instapaper-ios-device-and-version-stats-update) data says it really isn't worth it. And the "accepted" answer at [this stackover flow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291823/breakdown-of-ios-versions-being-used) even suggests just supporting 4.2!

Now, of course, you may have really good reasons for wanting to support 3, perhaps you are working with an Enterprise client who needs 3. In which case, just completely disregard what I've said.