# iOS5, iOS4, ... statistics?

Tags: ios, statistics

I'm looking for usage statistics of Apples iOS. Something like that http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp for browser usage.

Does anyone know a source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go to http://marketshare.hitslink.com/, view mobile browsers by version, then infer the iOS version market share from the version of Mobile Safari being reported. But keep in mind that it's not a direct translation between the two version numbers. Here's the version number translation I've been able to figure out (by seeing which iOS release came out the same month each new Safari version first appeared):

```
Mobile Safari Version     iOS Version
5.1                       5.0
5.0                       4.2-4.3
4.0                       3.0-4.1
3.1                       2.x
3.0                       1.x
```

By their metrics, iOS 5.0 is up to 35.61% (of all mobile phone web users) as of February, iOS 4.2-4.3 is down to 21.14%, and 3.0-4.1 is only 2.78%.

Comment: It appears that these are the global estimates.  Do you know of any sites that show a geographic breakdown?  The marketshare site will but you have to sign up and pay real money.

Comment: I don't know of anyone with this level of detail plus regional breakdowns for free. You can get free regional breakdowns at http://gs.statcounter.com/ but they don't show mobile versions so they're no help in answering your question. (By the way, they are used by different sites than NetApplications and their data favors a somewhat more tech-savvy and up-to-date demographic.)